# Resubmit app under new name with same bundle ID as original app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a dumb app on the app store that yrs later I got contacted saying that a company wants the name of the app because they have a website with that name.  I'm trying to change my app name to something else.  So in ITC, I submitted the form for an update to the app with a new name for the app.

In Xcode, I tried updating everything with the new name.  In Xcode 5, the only place I found I could do that was in the Product Name in build settings.  That then changed my Bundle Identifier in the General section, as well as the name of the app on the iPhone home page.  I created two new provisioning profiles for dev/release with that new name and I thought it was working fine until I tried to validate my archive and it said that I would have to submit a new app because the bundle ID doesn't match.  But if my Bundle ID matches the old name of the app, then on the iPhone home screen, it will still say the old name and not the new name.  Is there a way around submitting a new app in this case?  Thanks.

Comment: Why did you create new provisioning profiles just to rename an app? All you need to do is update the existing app.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, because I'm new to this.  I am just learning.  I still have the problem if I update the Product Name to a new name, then the bundle ID and product name won't match right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do in your project is change the "Bundle Name" from `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to whatever name you want to show under the icon. Don't change the actual `PRODUCT_NAME` value.

Then in iTunes Connect, add an update for your existing app and change the app's name.

Now submit the update. Done.